# Tornado's XSRF protection

Tags: python, cookies, tornado, csrf

I am using Facebook's Tornado web engine for Python for a project I'm doing and was planning on implementing the XSRF protection, but it left me a little confused.

On a typical request it sets an "_xsrf" cookie to the user's browser if it's not found and then matches that with the value embedded in an HTML form value the browser has sent with the request.

Well let's say an attacker did something like this:

```
<img src="blah.com/transfer_money?account=0098&destination=0099&_xsrf=
(whatever the client's cookie contains)" title="cool image" />
```

What's to prevent the attacker from using the cookie outright? As far as I can tell the cookies used for XSRF are not "secure" both from the [check_xsrf_cookie method and the xsrf_token method that actually generates the XSRF token](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#RequestHandler.check_xsrf_cookie). Am I missing something...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are asking what prevents attacker from accessing user's cookie in given domain.

Well, the answer is: **browser security policy**. The script from one domain cannot access cookie from other domain (most of the time). More details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

This can be circumvented by using [XSS (Cross-Site Scripting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack: injecting the script directly into the source of attacked page. Another approach is to break the client application (browser).

However, most of the time it is not possible for the attacker to retrieve user's cookie from other domain. Additional level of security would be to associate specific CSRF (or "*XSRF*") token with specific user (and to check it during validation).

Comment: Yeah, I'd be more inclined to check on a per-user basis. This is what is built-in with Tornado. It also offers secure cookies (e.g. cookies that are signed with a secret value only displayed in the application code) and I wondered why it wasn't "secured"; now I know.